# Faillog command on CentOS7

Tags: centos

Although EPEL7 has been installed, faillog seems not to be recognized:

```
[vagrant@vm-one ~]$ faillog
bash: faillog: command not found...
```

None of the packages seem to contain the `faillog` command:

```
[vagrant@vm-one ~]$ sudo yum whatprovides */faillog
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.cj2.nl
 * epel: mirror.serverbeheren.nl
 * extras: mirror.serverbeheren.nl
 * updates: mirror.cj2.nl
No matches found
```

Attempt three was to execute `sudo yum install <yum_url_faillog>` in order to install the command, but it does not seem to exist on [this overview](http://ftp.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/epel/7/x86_64/f/)

**Questions**

1. How to install faillog?
2. If it does not exist. Why does it not exist anymore and what command replaces faillog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended method for temporarily locking accounts in EL7 is with **pam_faillock**.

> To lock out any non-root user after three unsuccessful attempts and unlock that user after 10 minutes, add the following lines to the auth section of the /etc/pam.d/system-auth and /etc/pam.d/password-auth files:
>
> ```
>   auth        required       pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 unlock_time=600
>   auth        sufficient     pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
>   auth        [default=die]  pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 unlock_time=600
> ```
>
> Add the following line to the account section of both files specified in the previous step:
>
> ```
>   account     required      pam_faillock.so
> ```

To check a user's faillock count or reset their count use the `faillock` command.

For more information, see the Red Hat Security Guide: [4.1.3. Locking User Accounts After Failed Login Attempts](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/chap-Hardening_Your_System_with_Tools_and_Services.html#sec-Locking_User_Accounts_After_Failed_Login_Attempts)

Answer (score 1):

The faillog utility [was removed after CentOS 5](https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2110).

Comment: I did not find any information regarding this. I am curious to know the reason and the alternative command

Comment: The reference I found was: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2110

Comment: Please add the `pam_tally2` command that is mentioned in the link to the answer. If the link is deprecated the information is lost.